# Why won't chrome display this image properly?

Tags: image, google-chrome, firefox

I have an image that I can view with no issues with Windows image previewer but when I try to view it in Chrome I just get the following:

[image]

Here is a link to the file in my dropbox folder:

[view in dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/opyt0t46yncnm4r/TOUCTA01052A-0-1494263354.jpg?dl=0)

Weirdly the dropbox preview works fine but if you download the image and try to open it with chrome it doesnt work. If I try to open it with Firefox I get the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the image was actually a tiff that had been saved as a jpeg